# How to fetch data for multiple value from single column in php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I want to fetch data for multiple value from single column, but only the last one (price = 399) is visible on page.

I am using this code, please help I want to fetch data for all 3 prices.

```
<a href="show_products.php?price=149&price=299&price=399">
```

Comment: <a href="show_products.php?price=149&price=299&price=399">

Comment: @vivek here it is ---->  <a href="show_products.php?price=149&price=299&price=399">

Comment: i want the database query

Comment: if (isset($_GET['price']) && $_GET['price']<>"")
 {
  $productprice= $_GET['price'];
  $productprice_result=mysql_query("select * from products where price=$productprice");  
  $productprice_rows=mysql_fetch_array($productprice_result); 
  $productid=$productprice_rows["product_id"];
  $productsql=$productsql. "and price=$productprice ";
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (isset($_GET['price']) && $_GET['price']<>"") 
{ 
$productprice= $_GET['price'];
 $productprice_result=mysql_query("select * from products where price=$productprice"); 

while($productprice_rows=mysql_fetch_array($productprice_result)){ 

$productid=$productprice_rows["product_id"];
 $productsql=$productsql. "and price=$productprice "; 
}
```

try it

Comment: same result, only 399 product is displayed. php code is this, is it correct -->       <a href="show_products.php?price=149&price=299&price=399">

Comment: you are taking various price value in one name that is price try with different name for different price value